# VBA loop through column and store values in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have my column B, starting from cell 2 (because of the header) containing codes of type String. I would like to get a list of these codes. However, these codes are repeated a number of times. So I would like to loop through my column B and add to my array of codes whenever a new one is encountered, if that makes sense.

Here is my code. How can this be done ? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub List()

Dim listCodes() As String

With Worksheets("My sheet)

    nbr_lines = .Rows.Count
    Dim i As Long
   
    val_old = .Cells(2, 2).Value

    listCodes(1) = val_old 

    For i = 2 To nbr_lines
        val_new = .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        
        While val_old = val_new
            val_old = val_new
            
        Wend
        
        listCodes(i) = val_new
        val_old = val_new
    Next i
        

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest the use of a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd suggest a dictionary. Drop the entire column into an array for speedy processing first, then throw it all in the dictionary:

```
Sub List()

Dim listCodes() As Variant
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim nbr_lines As Long

With Worksheets("My sheet")
    
    'Get last used line and throw values in array;
    nbr_lines = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    listCodes = .Range("B2:B" & nbr_lines).Value
    
    'Loop array instead of cells for speed. Add all unique items into dictionary;
    For Each el In listCodes
        dict(el) = ""
    Next
    
    'Add the content of the dictionary to the sheet;
    .Range("C2").Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)

End With

End Sub
```

---

**Note:** This can also be achieved outside of VBA through easy formulae like the `UNIQUE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary approach. Below sub will copy only unique items to column `D`. Modify codes as your need.

```
Public Sub CopyUniqueOnly()
Dim i As Long

    Dim currCell As Range, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each currCell In .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            If Not dict.exists(currCell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(currCell) Then
                dict.Add currCell.Value, currCell.Value
            End If
        Next currCell
    End With
    
    Range("D2").Resize(dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
    
End Sub
```